# Conditional Functions in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I need some help on my code. I want to ask if it is possible to use the Boolean method in making the functions work like:

```
*Event Listeners*

if (A == true && B == false)
{
    function A (){
        *function A will work*
        *function B will not work*
    }

    if(A == false && B == true){
        function B(){
            *function B will work*
            *function A will not work*
        }

    }
}
```

or something like that. If it is possible or if this code works, is it possible to loop this and can I get an example of it?

Comment: Greetings and welcome to Stackoverflow.    Can you edit your question to be a bit clearer on what you're trying to do?  Add some context to the broader thing you're trying to accomplish.   That would help with getting a good answer.

Comment: I assume what you're trying to do is call different functions based off of two boolean values. So if A is true then function A is called, and if B is true then function B is called. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: What you are doing there is a violation of everything AS3 is.

Answer (score 0):

Uh... Your description is kinda vague so I am gonna use a very broad stroke to cover more bases. You should just put the if statements into the function themselves.

```
function Atrue():void {
  if (A == true && B == false) {
    //write your code here for function A
  }
}

function Btrue():void {
  if (A == false && B == true) {
    //write your code here for function B
  }
}
```

HOWEVER, Organis is right. This is a poor implementation. If at all possible, try to have the If condition satisfied before calling the functions instead of eliminating unwanted calls within the function itself. Maybe you should elaborate more.